# How to make this simple mod_rewrite work

Tags: mod-rewrite

I'm a bit of a newb so excuse the very simple challenge I'm having.

Basically, i'm using friendly url's and you can access articles on my site like so:

```
url.com/articles/article_name
```

Which translates on the server as

```
url.com/articles.php?article_url=article_name
```

If however, you visit

```
url.com/articles
```

It brings up an index of the articles. This all works as I'd planned.

**The problem is** when I load up

```
url.com/articles/
```

It causes some headaches. Ideally, '/articles' and '/articles/' would both load up an index.

My rewrite lines look like this:

```
RewriteRule ^articles$ articles.php
RewriteRule ^articles/(.*)$ articles.php?article_url=$1
```

Any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From memory, you need to make the trailing slash optional on the first rule:

```
RewriteRule ^articles/?$ articles.php
RewriteRule ^articles/(.+)$ articles.php?article_url=$1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^articles/*$ articles.php
RewriteRule ^articles/(.+)$ articles.php?article_url=$1
```

Comment: The first rewriterule you put has a forward slash in it but I want to be able to access it with both the slash and no slash. I'm not sure if I explained that very well... or does this accomplish it and I completely don't understand how the rules work?

Comment: * matches 0 or more occurences.